# How to rank product page based on users geo location?

Tags: seo, local-seo, localization

We have a product website with tie ups all over the country. Our product web page has products basic information, reviews, price and offers.

Most of our traffic comes like:
1. User type [Product-Name] on google,     if they see our websites product page, they click on that link.
2. Once they land to our product page, we show user price, offer from most popular city of our country.
3. If user wants to see price, offers of their location, they have to select their location on our product page. The price and offer varies based on our tie up with the local retailers.

I was reading google localization and trying to show offer, price on the seo link based on users location.

One option is to have multiple pages like [price-in-location]. This will create different pages for multiple location where we have tie ups. The problem is that these links only show up if user types  I.e. apple laptop price.  But most of our searches are just  I.e apple laptop. This only ranks our general apple product page where user has to fill his location information to get price,offer details.

How can I make my product page rank based on user location and show users relevant information directly.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. Once they land to our product page, we show user price, offer from most popular city of our country.
> 3. If user wants to see price, offers of their location, they have to select it on product page. The price and offer varies based on our tie up with the local retailers.

This structure of your web pages may not be useful for user experience.

Currently, the number of search queries "**near me**" has increased. According to Google:

> 76% of people who search for something nearby on their smartphone visit a related business within a day, and 28% of those searches result in a purchase.

Therefore, offering users yourself to choose the location convenient for them, you lose traffic from the query "**near me**".

In addition, you increase the number of clicks that a user must make to receive an answer to his request / purpose of the request. You increase the path to the final result of the search. However, here we must take into account the fact that Google considers such remote web pages less important than a closer web pages.

In order to get traffic from the search query "near me" you probably need to apply structured data for the type **[LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness)** (see below and choose More specific Types) with the following properties for each of your store / retailer (here only for location):

- **[address](https://schema.org/address)** with the embed type **[PostalAddress](https://schema.org/PostalAddress)**
- **[areaServed](https://schema.org/areaServed)**
- **[department](https://schema.org/department)**
- **[geo](https://schema.org/geo)** with the embed type **[GeoCoordinates](https://schema.org/GeoCoordinates)**
- **[hasMap](https://schema.org/hasMap)** - Here it can be useful to apply Google's guides: **[Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)** and **[Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)** and creating Google maps with directions for each retailer / store.

Create separate web pages for each of your store / retailers using the above structured data for localization. This will help you set separate prices for separate places. Also, it can help localize your products and drive traffic from searching "**near me**".

Read more the **[guide of Google to the type Local Business](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business)**.

[image]

Comment: "Create separate web pages for each of your store / retailers using the above structured data for localization."  I think you misunderstood the question. I want to rank my product page instead of seller's page. A single seller on my website can have multiple products i.e. a laptop, a bicycle. If user types on google "dell laptop", currently I am able to show product page for "dell laptop". Now, user has to select his/her location to check offers by local retailers.

Comment: You are taking route of ranking sellers instead of product which I don't want as I have complete product description, reviews on that page and I want to rank my product page only.

Comment: I am ready to put location information for each of my product i.e. if one product is available in 100 different locations, can I somehow indicate this in my product page's schema, which google can then pick to show localized results?

Comment: "You are taking route of ranking sellers instead of product which I don't want as I have complete product description, reviews on that page and I want to rank my product page only". Here the main intention is to localize your products. But since your products are sold by many sellers, then of course this applies to them as well. The right websites of wholesalers or product manufacturers always offer an option such as "Our sellers" or "Where you can buy it".

Comment: "I am ready to put location information for each of my product i.e. if one product is available in 100 different locations, can I somehow indicate this in my product page's schema, which google can then pick to show localized results?" - Of course, you can do this by applying the properties that I indicated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Google ranks pages on a country level only.   You can have different prices for different countries that rank appropriately within each country, but you can't have different pages for different states or cities that rank differently in different locations within a country.

Your solution of different pages for different cities is only going to work if people type in the name of the city.   In the case when people search for "dallas product" rather than just "product".  However, it sounds like you need a solution for when people search for just the product name.

You need to do a better job of guessing a user's location when showing them the price on the page.   Rather than showing the price for the most popular city you have three options:

1. Use a geo-ip database.   The nice thing about them is that they can usually get your user in the right state, often within a couple hundred miles of their actual location.  The user doesn't need to give you any special permissions.   They are however often inaccurate.   Plus they are easily thrown off by proxies and VPNs.  If you use this solution you need to have a way for users to change their auto-detected location.
2. Ask the user to allow their browser to share their location with you.   The downside is that it looks really intrusive with a popup.  That is especially true if you ask when the page loads.   I like the sites that ask me to share my location when I click on the "change" button to change my location.

Comment: There's something we are missing here.. if I type 'used laptop'.. google suggests me classified websites with pages having "used laptop" in my current city. How is this happening? I didn't type city name in my query.. still able to see apt result. Why can't I do the same for my use case.

Comment: Also, I read this article: https://searchengineland.com/things-near-seo-268697 . This also suggests that we need to put our location in our search query to get the location based result

Comment: That is an interesting point.  Map searches or "local" searches certainly do what you want.   I think you'd have to get all the places that sell your product to add your product as a category to their business.    I don't have any experience in that area and I'm just guessing, so I won't add it to my answer.    I'm not sure exactly how you would convince Google to put a local results box up when people search your product name.  I'll let somebody else answer if they have relevant experience with local results for a specific product search.